# How to export an instances in ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For this question, lets consider the following export

```
export { MyClassA, MyClassB, MyClassC }
```

which I would like to change such that for `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` instances are exported. Now I would expect I can do

```
export { new MyClassA() as myclassa, new MyClassB() as myclassb, MyClassC };
```

which doesn't work. It seems that this is not possible. It feels a bit like you want to call a function with an instance parameter

```
someFunction(new MyClassA());
```

But you have to write this like

```
let myclassa =  new MyClassA();
someFunction(myclassa);
```

Now because `someFunction(new MyClassA())` does work, I would expect something simular with `export`

Now before I rewrite this to

```
let myclassa = new MyClassA(), myclassb = new MyClassB();
export {myclassa, myclassb, MyClassC};
```

I'm curious if what I tried is somehow possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules export bindings, not actual values. The only case where you don't need an explicit binding is a default export:

```
export default class { ... };

export default 1;
```

So the following should work too:

```
export default new MyClassA();
```

Of course, there is only one default export, so in your case you need to create bindings first. If you do it your way or as the others suggested is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

you can:

```
export let myInstanceA = new MyClassA();
```

as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no es6 import grammar support it directly. But what you can do is:

- If you want to be singleton, you can new it before export it like:

  `// in file.js
  class A {...}
  export const a = new A();
  // use it 
  import {a} from './file';`
- If you want to be multi instances, you can export it, then instantiate it outside, like:

  `// in file.js
  export class A {...}
  // use it 
  import {A} from './file';
  let a1 = new A();
  let a2 = new A();`